# On isomorphism of a field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field, $\alpha \notin F$, and denote $F(\alpha)$ as a field of fractions that contain $F$ and $\alpha$. Is it true that $\frac{F({\alpha})}{(\alpha)}$ is isomorphic to $F$?

Comment: Well $F(\alpha)$ is a field and fields don't have non-trivial quotients.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg what can we say that if $\alpha$ is transcendental?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is transcendental, then $F[\alpha]/(\alpha)\cong F$, but note that $F[\alpha]\ne F(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F(\alpha)$ is a field, then $(\alpha)=F(\alpha)$ (since $\alpha\neq0$, it is invertible), and the quotient has just a single element.